# Python: iterating dictionaries with for

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, iteration

suppose  I have two dictionaries

```
x = {'a': 5, 'b': 4} 
y = {'a': 8, 'b': 3}
```

and I want to print 'x' and 'y' values for 'a' and 'b' by mentioning that those 'x' and 'y' values are for `a` and `b` using for loop. How can I do that? I am beginner please help me with the syntax here.

It should be like

```
a
x:5
y:8

b
x:4
y:3
```

Comment: Actually I am able to iterate x and y values of a and b iterating key in x{} but I don't know how to print "a" and "b" in loop. What I am supposed to write in the first print statement so that print "a" and "b".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code and clear description of the problem with it

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the keys and print the corresponding values:

```
for key in x.iterkeys():
    print key
    print 'x:%d' % x[key]
    print 'y:%d' % y[key]
    print
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in list(your_dict.values()):
    print i
```